# How to configure tika service within k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, tika-server

We are using tika to extract text from a lot of documents,
for this we need to give tika service custom config file (xml)

While in docker you can do it just the same as it appears in [tika docker image instructions](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker#custom-config):

```
docker run -d -p 9998:9998 -v `pwd`/tika-config.xml:/tika-config.xml apache/tika:1.25-full --config /tika-config.xml
```

I don't know how to achieve the same result with k8s deployment

The deployment I'm using now is this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tika
  labels:
    app: tika
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tika
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tika
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tika
          image: apache/tika:2.4.0
```

How can I add a custom config to this image?

Comment: I would convert the .xml files using [this tool](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-to-yaml) to a Kubernetes yaml configmap. Then I would follow [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) can be used to load xml file.